# UIButton Action not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I add an button to subview in class A and want a method to be called at button pressed in class B.

Class A:

INI-Method:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame target:(id)target action:(SEL)action
```

addTarget in INI-Method:

```
[_playButton addTarget:target
                action:action
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Class B:

call the initMethod

```
photoView = [[PhotoView alloc] initWithFrame:frame target:self action:@selector(playButtonPressed:)];
```

Action-Method

```
-(void)playButtonPressed:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"Play Button");
}
```

Can you tell me why I see the UIButton but there is no reaction on touch.

Full INI-Method:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame target:(id)target action:(SEL)action
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
self.clipsToBounds = YES;
self.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
// self.contentSize = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height);

// create the image view
_imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
_imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
_imageView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
_playButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 40)];
[_playButton addTarget:target
                action:action
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_playButton setTitle:@"PLAY" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
_playButton.center = CGPointMake(160.0, 200.0);// for center
[_imageView addSubview:_playButton];

self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
[self addSubview:_imageView];

return self;
}
```

Comment: comment this line self.userInteractionEnabled = NO; & then test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting `userInteractionEnabled` to NO will make the view ignore any touches in the view or it's subviews. Just removed this line.

---

Try and replace the control event for `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`

The`UIControlEventTouchUpOutside` will be trigged when the touch up was detect outside of the bounds of the button.

The `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` is used to detect a touch-up in side the bounds of a button.

Comment: Thx for that hint.
After change to UIControlEventTouchUpInside there is still no reaction.

Comment: _playButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 40)];

Comment: Can you post the full `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame target:(id)target action:(SEL)action`

Comment: added in the initial question

Comment: You set the views user interaction to no: `self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;` then all touch will be ignored, even in subViews.

Comment: Thx! That was the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
[_playButton addTarget:target
                action:action
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
```

For this:

```
[_playButton addTarget:target
                action:action
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Thx for the hint -> damn intellisense ;-)

But still no reaction on tab!